# New features for Processing game/desk accessory

Tags: processing

I have written a simple desk accessory in Proccessing called Trip, you can see it below. It is working, but it is very simple, and needs more features.

```
import processing.pdf.*;

PImage tardis;
int flash = 0;

void setup() {
  size(256, 256);
  frame.setResizable(true);
  tardis = loadImage("TARDIS1.jpg");
  beginRecord(PDF, "trip.pdf");
  background(random(100), random(100), random(100));
  randomSeed(299792458);
}
void draw() {
  stroke(random(100), random(100), random(100));
  line(random(width), random(height), mouseX, mouseY);
  if (flash == 1) {
    background(random(100), random(100), random(100));
  }
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (key == 's') {
    endRecord();
    exit();
  }
  else if (key == 'q') {
    exit();
  }
  else if (key == 'b') {
    background(random(100), random(100), random(100));
  }
  else if (key == 't') {
    image(tardis ,0 ,0, width, height);
  }
  else if (key == 'f') {
    if (flash == 0) {
      flash = 1;
    }
    else if (flash == 1) {
      flash = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

I would appreciate any new ideas for features, particularly Easter egg-style secret features.

Answer (score -1):

How about something where if you change the background to a particular color, something cool happens?

Like if it turns full black,`(0,0,0)`, it causes an image to pop up on screen.

Comment: Hi, thanks for joining CodeReview. Although it is good to answer questions, try to answer questions only that are within scope of the site. CodeReview is not intended for questions about feature requests.